# How can i get a path relative from an other?

Tags: python, python-os

[image: Visualization] I have a path1 relative from a path2 and I want to get this path1 from my script which isn't path1 or path2. I know the absolute path of path2.

Comment: You might want to show some examples of what you're trying to do so it's clear what you mean. Also, if you've written some code that attempts to do what you want, you should show that too.

Comment: It's not clear what you want; is it just `os.path.join(path2, path1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made my own funtion

```
import pathlib

def convert_path(path, org_path):
    org_path = pathlib.Path(org_path).parent # need the folder where my file is
    for element in path.split(os.path.sep):
        if element == "..":
            org_path = org_path.parent
        else:
            org_path = org_path.joinpath(element)
    return str(org_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`os.relpath`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) function for this:

> **`os.path.relpath(path[, start])`**
>
> Return a **relative filepath to `path`** either from the current directory or from an optional `start` directory. This is a path computation: the filesystem is not accessed to confirm the existence or nature of `path` or `start`.

So you can call:

```
>>> relpath('/home/foo/bar', '/home/qux')
'../foo/bar'
```

So you can access `/home/foo/bar` from `/home/qux` by the relative path `../foo/bar`.

Or for your case:

```
replath(path2, path_of_script)
```

where `path2` is an absolute path.